# How to get helm module codebase?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm new to helm charts, want to do the customisation to existing public chart, anyway to do it?
We are okay to host it at our end, just wanted to check how to dump the existing helm chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below if you want to pull the helm chart at your local to customise it -

```
helm pull [chart URL | repo/chartname] [...] [flags]
```

Example -

```
helm repo add <name> <url>
helm pull repo-name/chart-name
```

Then you can customise it as per your need.

Any further explanation needed then let me know